# Finding a specific Isomorphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While I was reading about Isomorphism and sets, I came across with the following question:

> Find a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is Isomorphism to $\mathbb{N} \oplus \mathbb{N}$.

Firstly I tried to think of a subset like this, but my creativity has failed me. Later I tried to find some information about it through the Internet, but hasn't yet found. How hard is it really to think of a simple solution?

Comment: as a semigroup?     --

Comment: For instance take $\{n\alpha + m \beta : n, m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ with  $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}+\beta$

Comment: @Timkinsella can you give an explanation about it? still can't see how does it help

Comment: Try to prove $(n,m) \mapsto n\alpha + m \beta$ is an isomorphism from $\mathbb{N} \oplus \mathbb{N}$ to its image in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think the OP is talking if isomorphism as **sets**...since, of course, $\;\Bbb N\oplus\Bbb N\;$ has no clear meaning...and thus, and I'm guessing, that weird thing "direct sum" probably simply means "Cartesian product"

Answer (score 1):

Find a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is <s>Isomorphism</s> to $\mathbb{N} \oplus \mathbb{N}$.

This should say

Find a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N} \oplus \mathbb{N}$.

The set $\{ a+ b\sqrt 2 : a,b\in \mathbb N \}$ will serve, because the correspondence between  $a+b\sqrt 2$ and $(a,b)$ is an isomorphism.

However $\{a+br : a,b\in\mathbb N\}$ cannot serve if $r$ is rational. For example, suppose $r=22/7.$ Then $0 + 7r = 22 + 0r,$ so only one number, $22,$ would correspond to two different pairts of members of $\mathbb N,$ namely $(0,7)$ and $(22,0).$